# is an equivalent of singleton_variable_set available in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need the equivalent of a `singleton_variable_set` in Ruby for my use case. But no such exists:

```
> A = Class.new
=> A 
> A.respond_to? :instance_variable_set
=> true 
> A.respond_to? :class_variable_set
=> true 
> A.respond_to? :class_instance_variable_set
=> false 
A.respond_to? :singleton_variable_set
 => false
```

Why do I need it? I am creating an anonymous class, which has a binding in the containing method to a variable I will need in my anonymous class as both an instance method and a singleton method of the class:

```
def prepare(ac_relation)
  Class.new ActionContainer::Base do
        mattr_accessor :ac_relation
        instance_variable_set(:@ac_relation, ac_relation)
        singleton_variable_set(:@ac_relation, ac_relation)
  end
end
```

I need ac_relation available as both an instance and singleton method of the newly created anonymous class. Unfortunately, singleton_variable_set does not exist. How can I achieve what I want?

This is a working solution I came up with but I don't like it:

```
val = 2

c = Class.new do
  attr_accessor :cc
  class << self
    attr_accessor :cc
  end

  @cc = 2
  instance_variable_set(:@cc, val)

  def initialize
    @cc = self.class.instance_variable_get(:@cc)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same could be accomplished within the block using a singleton method to retrieve a value:

```
Class.new(ActionContainer::Base) do 
  define_singleton_method(:ac_relation) { @ac_relation }
  @ac_relation = ac_relation
end
```

If you need a public setter:

```
define_singleton_method(:ac_relation=) { |value| @ac_relation = value }
```

This would avoid the visibility issues and need to call `instance_variable_get` on the class within another method.

So you don't really NEED a `singleton_variable_set` method. The block is executed within the context of the class, so defining an instance variable within it is the same as:

```
class MyClass
  class << self
    # Defining instance variables here
  end
end
```

You simply need a way to access them.

```
def prepare(some_value)
  Class.new do 
    define_singleton_method(:ac_relation) { @ac_relation }
    define_singleton_method(:ac_relation=) { |value| @ac_relation = value }
    @ac_relation = some_value
  end
end

klass = prepare("foobar")
klass.ac_relation
#=> "foobar"
```

Comment: I have not tried it out yet but it looks cleaner than what I have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if we can do that but if all you need is some method to be available on both instance and class level, you can do something like this with the use of a module,

```
module SampleModule

  module ClassMethods
    def sample_method params
      ...
    end
  end

  def sample_method params
    ...
  end

  def self.included base
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

end
```

You include this module in your class and it'll expose the instance method and by the `self.included` block it'll also expose the method at class level.

Hope this helps